# How do I remove the white border between my header image and iframe?

Tags: iframe, header, space

I am looking to have a one page website with a header image at the top that spreads with width of the browser page, and an Iframe below it display another site. I have accomplished this mostly (thanks to a code from stackoverlow) but the problem is there a white space below my header image, before my iframe appears. Any idea how to remove this or thoughts on other ways to accomplish my webpage? Here is the code I have so far.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<style>
*{margin:0;padding:0}
html, body {height:100%;width:100%;overflow:hidden}
table {height:100%;width:100%;table-layout:static;border-collapse:collapse}
iframe {height:100%;width:100%}

.header {border-bottom:1px solid #000}
.content {height:100%}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
  <tr><td class="header"><div><h1>Header</h1></div></td></tr>
  <tr><td class="content">
    <iframe src="http://google.com/" frameborder="0"></td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try
    border: none;

or

```
border: 0;
```